# Upgrade Wordpress core programmatically with PHP?

Tags: php

I want to upgrade to the latest WordPress version, with PHP.

```
if(isset($_GET['core-update'])){
        require_once('wp-load.php'); 
}
```

Tried:

```
1 - wp_update_core();
2 - wp_maybe_auto_update();
3 - Core_Upgrader::upgrade();
```

All that i found online or in the WordPress codex. For my idea this should be a really simple function, but what am i missing?

Same for plugin functions like:

This is working:
deactivate_plugins("classic-editor/classic-editor.php",true);
And deactivates the plugin.

But this isn't working:
uninstall_plugin("classic-editor/classic-editor.php");

Al though both are real functions in de codex.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use PHP? If you want to do it programmatically it would be easier to use something like WP CLI.

Comment: Using CLI already and love it. But this is for hundreds of websites, all different servers. Making one global script to roll out faster.

Comment: @Silver Did you get any solution for the script to update the WordPress website to different servers? if you got it, can you please share it with me, I also have the same thing want to implement, and your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same question, searched everywhere but sadly there was no straightforward solution I could find.

I then spent the last 36 hours working on different methods, but then tried to do something with the WP-CLI that can work by simply calling reinstallWordpress(). I hope this helps!

I have tested this from within a custom plugin and it worked. I think it should work in your functions.php, too! Just check it out. Enjoy!

```
/**
 * This function basically forces WordPress to reinstall itself
 * It does the following...
 * 
 * 1. wGet the wp-cli.phar file and place in current directory to allow
 * executing WP-CLI command within file.
 * 
 * 2. Replace $wp_version in 'root/wp-includes/version.php' to an
 * outdated WordPress version for the 'core update' command to upgrade, or
 * reinstall WordPress technically.
 * 
 * 3. Update WordPress with the WP-CLI command.
 * 
 * 4. Delete wp-cli.phar.
**/
function reinstallWordpress() {
    $wpCLIFile = 'wp-cli.phar';
    $rootPATH = '/home/user/website.com/'; // Define your root path here
    
    // Require wp-includes/version.php
    $versionFile = $rootPATH . 'wp-includes/version.php';
    require $versionFile;
    
    // Get wp-cli.phar
    if (!file_exists($wpCLIFile)) {
        exec("wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar");
    }
    
    // Replace current version to an outdated version
    $outdatedVersion = '5.9.3'; // Recommended if you're using the current version 6.1.1, but you can further test and change this value
    $currentVersion = $wp_version;
    file_put_contents($versionFile, str_replace("$currentVersion", "$outdatedVersion", file_get_contents($versionFile)));
    
    // Update WordPress with the WP-CLI
    $output = array();
    $full_command = "php wp-cli.phar core update 2>&1";
    exec($full_command, $output);
    
    // Delete wp-cli.phar from directory
    unlink($wpCLIFile);
    
    // Check if reinstall was successful
    $stringifiedOutput = implode(" ", $output);
    if (strpos($stringifiedOutput, "WordPress updated successfully")) {
        return "successful";
    } else {
        return "failed";
    }
}
```